Search related table using Entity Framework 6
I have a legacy quote system that has a table for Quotes and a related table for QuoteLineItems.
How do I search the QuoteLineItems?
I have tried the below:
allrecords.Where(s => s.ClientsName.ToLower().Contains(search) || 
                      s.QuoteLineItems.Select(xd => xd.Description.ToLower()).Contains(search) || 
                      s.QuoteID == quoteID);

The search only matches the exact word but does not match if there is anything before or after the search word.
Example, if I search for "Test", then any QuoteLineItem with only the word "Test" in the description is found, but the search does find the search term if it is not an exact match like "This is a Test" or "Testing 123".
NOTE: the ClientsName search works perfectly.

To resolve the issue I refactored the query to use Any for checking if any items in the collection match the criteria. Here is the corrected code:
allrecords.Where(s => s.ClientsName.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                      s.QuoteLineItems.Any(xd => xd.Description.ToLower().Contains(search)) ||
                      s.QuoteID == quoteID);

